# State if the statement is True or False: The maximum value of $2x^3-9x^2-24x-20$ is $-7$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, maxima-minima

> State if the statement is True or False:
>   The maximum value of $2x^3-9x^2-24x-20$ is $-7$.

Let $f(x) = 2x^3-9x^2-24x-20$.

If we go by the derivative test:
$$f'(x) = 6x^2-18x-24 \ \ \& \  \ f'(x) = 0 \implies x=4,-1$$

At $x=-1$ we get $f(x)=-7$ and at $x=4$ we get $f(x) = -132$, so we have maximum value $-7$ by this method.

But this is a polynomial function, its value tends to infinity as $x \to \infty$.

So what can be said about the truth of the statement?

Comment: Every local maximum $x$ of $f$ has $f'(x) = 0$, since $\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$ is negative for small $h > 0$ and positive for small $h < 0$; since $f$ is differentiable at $x$, the limit must equal $0$. That's necessary but not sufficient; as you note, $f$ is clearly unbounded.

Comment: $f'(x) = 0 at local minimums also. Look at the dominating first term for the global max and mins.

Comment: When they say "maximum" or "minimum" without qualification, they are generally referring to global phenomena, not local phenomena. So the statement is false.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $x=10^{20}$. That should do it.

Comment: x=10 will also give positive value!

Comment: Well, there's your answer, @user8795.

Comment: I think @anomaly's comment should be an answer and my answer should have been a comment. If you're looking for a quick, simple answer, though, mine will do the job if you recall the definition of what a maximum is.

Answer (score 0):

$f^{\prime\prime}(-1)=12(-1)-18=-30<0$. Thus $f$ has a local maximum at $-1$ and the local maximum value is $f(-1)=-7$. But it does not mean $f$ can not assume any value greater than $-7$. In fact the function $f$ is clearly unbounded. Here $f^{\prime}(x)>0$ for all $x\in (-\infty,-1)$ and for all $x\in (4,\infty)$ and $f^{\prime}(x)<0$ for all $x\in (-1,4)$. Thus $f$ is strictly increasing in $(-\infty,-1)\cup (4,\infty)$ and is strictly decreasing in $(-1,4)$. At $-1$ it has a local maximum and at $4$ it has a local minimum.

Comment: so the conclusion is false?

Comment: Unless the word "local" is mentioned, it is certainly false.

Answer (score 0):

The differentiation & setting of the derivative to zero yields *stationary* points. A *range-of-x* ought to have been specified for this question, as without it it is ill-posed.

To say that the function *has* a maximum value *of ∞ at x=∞* is a *scrambling* of the meaning of what's going-on, which is that the function increases without limit as *x* increases  without limit, & therefore *does not **have*** a maximum value. If a range of *x* had been given, you would compare the -7 gotten as a local maximum to the value taken by the function at the upper end of the range of *x* (you need not consider the *lower* end of the range of *x* as the function is *decreasing* without limit in that direction) ... and whichever were the greater would be the answer to the question.

A fussy little point though: but it's important in many kinds of problem: the range would have to be a *closed* range - ie of the form $$a\leq x\leq b ,$$ often denoted $$x\in[a,b], $$ rather than what is called an *open* range $$a< x< b ,$$ often denoted $$x\in(a,b) ;$$ as if it were the *latter* that were specified, you would technically *still* have the problem of the non-existence of a maximum value of the function if the upper limit of the range were such that it could exceed -7 for *x* still less than it.

Answer (score 0):

Assume the opposite:

$$2x^3-9x^2-24x-20>-7$$
$$\to 2x^3-9x^2-24x-13>0$$

$$\to (2x-13)(x+1)^2>0$$
Pretty blatant from this.

Comment: Your use of implication (" $\to$ ") is not enough. One must be able to go from your last inequality to your first. Indeed, this is possible, but you haven't made that clear.

Answer (score 0):

For large enough $x$, the polynomial grows unboundedly, therefore no finite maximum exists for the function. The points then you found, are just **local** maximum or minimum **not global**